# mysql query to assign value to the same variable from different columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which has many columns but there are two main columns called `District` and `State`. My sql query is as follows.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE District = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Date DESC";
```

this query returns me data from the district column.

Now this is what I want.In some rows the `District` column is empty, so in that case I want the query to lift data from `State` column. Is that possible?

Can that be done in mysql query or will I have to write something in php?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lift' ?

Comment: How I understood your question you will need `coalesce` function

Comment: try with adding a  "Or state == .$var"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what do you mean by empty? If it is `NULL` then you should use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(District, State) NewDistrict
FROM...
```

but if it is empty as `''`. then

```
SELECT *, IF(District = '', State, District) NewDistrict
FROM...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE District = '$var' 
  OR (District='' AND State='var') 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE District = '" . $var . "' OR State = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Date DESC";
```

Comment: Isn't this open to injection?

Comment: @Ck- that is off topic. Besides: depends on if the value of $var is escaped, I'd say...

Comment: @arkascha: even if it were escaped, it's rather clear that the OP isn't using prepared statements, so the code will almost certainly be unsafe

Comment: @arkascha I don't know PHP much, so I was just curious to know. Plus a cursor to the OP that he should be aware of this.

Comment: @Ck- sure, makes sense. But then you should add that comment to the question, not to this answer...